# Spawn ENOENT Error with npm install

Tags: windows, installation, npm, karma-runner

everytime I try to run npm install I get an ENOENT error with the following log:

```
2563 error Error: spawn ENOENT
2563 error     at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
2563 error     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
2564 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
2564 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
2564 error or email it to:
2564 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
2565 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
2566 error command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program              Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phantomjs"
2567 error cwd C:\Users\Tyler
2568 error node -v v0.10.12
2569 error npm -v 1.2.32
2570 error syscall spawn
2571 error code ENOENT
2572 error errno ENOENT
2573 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I've pasted the full log found in npm-debug.log here: http://pastebin.com/8PB8JRzW

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, have set my PYTHON environment variable, have MSVS2012, installed node-gyp, and am running the command line as an administrator. Any thoughts on how to get npm install to work? Thanks!

Comment: ENOENT says a file or directory was not found. Your line 2566 above has a very big gap between Program and Files. Could it be that this pathname is is the one that was not found? You could try installing into a different location that has no spaces in the path.

Answer (score 2):

As per https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/277#issuecomment-25943524:

> 1. Make Sure Your Python and node are both x86 (32Bit) or both x86-x64 (64Bit), a mix will throw this error
> 2. Set the environment variable PYTHON to your python.exe, in my case I ran "set PYTHON=E:\Python27\python.exe" before running npm